# how can I do a multiple track mix down on nuendo4?

Tags: nuendo, techniques, daw

I edit and master voice-overs during the week, most of them are short questions, answers or statements. What I would like to know is if there is a quick way of exporting all of the events/sounds in the tracks to replace their original ones? This would save me time, as I would not need to rename any of the sounds that I fixed, I could just replace them with the new versions.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then there are two principle ways:

- Solo the tracks you want to mixdown (ie: all the "John" voice talent tracks), Select all files you're interested in, press [**Apple + P**], then go [**file > export > audio mixdown**]. You can re-import and replace the files or select the option [**import into project** (or something along those lines)]. You'll have to delete or mute the old files though. Make sure you save the project as a new name just to be safe.
- If you are only interested in one track with multiple events, then [**press number "2"** (or second button in your tool bar) --> **highlight all the files on the track** > **right click** >  **audio menu** > **Bounce to Selection** > **Replace**]

That should do it. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: alright, but if all the events are diferent lengths would setting the parameter (apple P) be defined by the longest event? i.e one event A is 2 seconds and the other B is 30 seconds resulting in the mix down being all of the tracks together and the final mix will be A+B but 30 seconds long, a not a final mix of A sec and B 30sec.

 Reason being I need to make level adjustments to (re-master) individual voice takes, like the question and the answer but they must be seperate export files

Comment: @Jm-V   Yeah, exactly. So basically when you select everything and then press [Apple + P] it will select the left and right locators automatically for your whole project. you can do it manually too by dragging the locators on your ruler bar at the top. If you only select one event, you will only be selecting the locators around that event. I re-read your question, and I think your best option is doing the second suggestion in my answer.

Comment: hsve you tried doing it?

Comment: @jm all the time. Why, are you having issues? 